# How to insert a row into a table that has only a single autoincrement column?

Tags: sql, mysql

My table has only a single column calld *id*.  This column is an autoincrementing key (I am using it for sequencing).  I want to do something like: `insert into sequencer;` but this gives me SQL errors because I guess I need to have a `values` portion.  But there are no other columns in the table and I want the *id* column to be autoincremented.  I'd also rather not hack this by just adding another dummy column.  Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table SET id = NULL;
```

or

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (NULL);
```

When inserting `NULL` into an auto-increment column, mysql will generate a new number instead.

Comment: Yep, and MySQL's auto-increment also generates a new number when you try to insert zero.

Comment: If `SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"` is `SET` then a zero is a valid number. So use `NULL` just in case. -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero