# Auto Increment failing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 2 similar tables. One with an auto increment value and one without. The first table first column is defined as `INT(11), PRIMARY UNIQUE INDEX` and under EXTRA in phpmyadmin it says `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

This code does not work and does not add any values.

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO testtable1 VALUES ('', 'zzz', 'yyy')") ;
```

The second table is the same table with the first column dropped. This code works.

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO testtable2 VALUES ('jjj', 'fff')") ;
```

Any idea what I am missing? Running 7.2 on the database.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  Is there an error?  What is that error?  If you're just testing the queries themselves then remove PHP from the equation and just test the queries directly against the database.  What are the table definitions?  What are the results of each of these queries?  What were the expected results?

Comment: I agree. Especially since you will be using queries to get values out of the table. In the same phpmyadmjn web view,  see what works by testing different sql statements.

Comment: No errors. It just no longer adds the values. The code has worked like this for 13 years.

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading this correctly, the first table has an int(11) with `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

This means you should use similar query as in table 2. As in only pass in values for the two non auto increments fields.

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO testtable1 VALUES ('zzz', 'yyy')") ;
```

This will work as long as there are 3 fields, the first one is an auto inc int and the other two are strings. This is because auto inc handles the first column automatically.

Also, please check out this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or search for php MySQL predated statements to use prepared statements instead for some safety. It will help you against sql injections.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your `testtable1` has a definition reasonably similar to (pseudo-notation):

```
testtable1
------------
ID             INT      PK AUTOINCREMENT
SomeColumn     NVARCHAR
AnotherColumn  NVARCHAR
```

So when you do this:

```
INSERT INTO testtable1 VALUES ('', 'zzz', 'yyy')
```

You're explicitly telling the database to insert an empty string into an `INT` column.  Which won't work.

An `AUTOINCREMENT` column doesn't need to be told there's an empty value, it will automatically increment.  Just specify the values that you are inserting:

```
INSERT INTO testtable1 (SomeColumn, AnotherColumn) VALUES ('zzz', 'yyy')
```

Let the database engine handle the `ID` column.  In general it's pretty much always worth explicitly specifying the columns into which you are inserting values or from which you are selecting values.  It makes the code easier to read/support and reduces the chance of bugs/errors if the table definition ever slightly changes.

Comment: @GarryJones: Well, in all honesty, relying on poor coding practices to be future-proof isn't ever the best idea.  I can appreciate that there will be a lot of changes to make in the code, but those changes should be made anyway.  What you have is a mass of technical debt which has come back to be resolved.  In SQL code there's rarely any value in reducing the code size to save a few keystrokes, being as explicit as possible is pretty much always the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. It works. My code has worked for 13 years so something has changed at my providers. However I actually want to create an id number to refer to. 

The table I actually want to get working only has the id auto increment column
    
- - mysqli_query($conned, "INSERT INTO testtable1 () VALUES ()") ;  -- does not add the row. 

How do I do this?

Comment: After creating the value I usually pick it up with mysqli_insert_id - I only added the other two columns to see if I could work out why it wasn't working. So when you have a table with one column which is Auto Increment how does it work?

Comment: @GarryJones: Maybe add a column just to insert a dummy value?  Having a table with nothing but an ID is pretty uncommon.

Comment: Somebody here did not want to add a dummy column, But the solution he was told no longer works probably because of the same upgrade.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242623/how-to-insert-a-row-into-a-table-that-has-only-a-single-autoincrement-column

Comment: And I have now found the root cause of the error. MariaDB has updated the way auto increments are handled. I am on a 10.3x version, my working databases are all on a 10.1.x version, MariaDB updated on 10.23